# Посчитать количество элементов в массиве JSON с определенным значением на PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

У меня есть таблица `credits` с полем `data` в JSON формате, которое содержит такие значения:

```
[{"currency": "RUB", "category": "05"}, {"currency": "RUB",  "category": "04"}, {"currency": "USD", "category": "04"}]
[{"currency": "USD", "category": "06"}, {"currency": "RUB",  "category": "04"}, {"currency": "EUR", "category": "04"}]
[{"currency": "USD", "category": "04"}, {"currency": "RUB",  "category": "05"}, {"currency": "RUB", "category": "05"}]
```

Как можно вывести количество для каждой строки, где currency = "RUB" с помощью PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно как-то так:

```
WITH foo AS (SELECT ('[{"currency": "RUB", "category": "05"},' ||
                     ' {"currency": "RUB", "category": "04"},' ||
                     ' {"currency": "USD", "category": "04"}]')::json AS json)
SELECT COUNT(el)
FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(foo.json) AS el from foo) AS currency_list
WHERE el->>'currency'='RUB';
```

- `json_array_elements` представляет json-массив в виде набора значений
- операция `->>` запрашивает значение json в виде текста по заданному ключу.

---

> Как можно вывести количество для каждой строки

Просто выполнить запрос выше для каждой строки:

```
SELECT (
  SELECT COUNT(el)
  FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(data) AS el) AS currency_list
  WHERE el->>'currency'='RUB')
FROM credits;
```

---

За подробностями см. [документацию postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html)

Comment: а как выводить количество для каждой строки, если эти значения содержатся в поле _data_ ?

Comment: @Archie, добавил в ответ... на будущее: посторайся не переписывать ту часть вопроса на которую уже дан ответ...

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ и замечание, учту.